# Single key combination to clean text input in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

In Linux, is there any way I can put cursor inside some text input, like browser URL/quick search box, and just clear it?

Right now I have to select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>Del</kbd>. It does seem easy but becomes annoying really fast when you need to repeat it for a number of times.

Is there any single key combination for that?

Comment: If you select all, you can just overwrite the selection without having to delete it …

Comment: I'm not typing, I'm pasting with the middle button

Comment: Well, if you're up for a keyboard shortcut, why not paste with `Ctrl-V`?

Comment: b/c I'm copying into selection buffer and not clipboard :)

Comment: Ah, very well then, sorry for the confusion :)